# Custom function in google sheet using indexOf

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, indexof

I've got a list of emails that I need to clean and identify which of these emails are company emails (i.e info@, hello@, etc)

I've had an idea to add rows in one google sheet, then check this against another google sheet with a column of company alias'. This will then return `True`of `False` in the column `Company Alias?` in the Input sheet.

Here is my [Google sheet example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RkIo1ktjqzsccnEsw9ETg8Cxmbv21IX6HHh4X81f2D0/edit?usp=sharing)

I think it needs to iterate through the values of the second sheet and compare for `email 1` field in the first sheet to see if it contains that value. I have made an apps script below:

```
function CHECKALIAS(x) {

var app = SpreadsheetApp;  
var aliasSheet = app.getActive().getSheetByName('Company_Alias').getRange(2, 1, 45, 1);  
var aliasRange = aliasSheet.getValues();
var str = x;

if(str.indexOf(aliasRange) !== -1){
  return false;
  } else {
  return true;
  }  

}
```

**I get the below error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined (line 13, file "Code")
```

Comment: x is equal to str that's why you get an error, where do you make use of this function, in other words from where the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the function without passing it a value? It's giving you the error because `str` has no value.

Anyway, there's no need for a custom function here. This will return true if there's a match with one of the aliases.

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, JOIN("|",FILTER(Company_Alias!A2:A, NOT(ISBLANK(Company_Alias!A2:A)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a string and `aliasRange` is an array. Instead of searching for the array in the string, you should search for the string in the array.

Another problem is that `.getValues​​()` returns an array of arrays:

```
[["info @"], ["support @"], ["sales @"], ...].
```

To transform it into a 1D array, use the `flat()` function:

```
function CHECKALIAS(x) {
  let app = SpreadsheetApp;
  let aliasSheet = app.getActive().getSheetByName('Company_Alias').getRange(2, 1, 45, 1);
  let aliasRange = aliasSheet.getValues().flat(); // Transforms 2D array in 1D

  let userDomain = x.split('@'); // split "admin@somedomain.com"  into  [ "admin", "somedomain.com" ]
  let usr = userDomain[0] + '@'; // "admin@

  return aliasRange.indexOf(usr) !== -1; // Is usr in aliasRange?
}
```